# Find a xml element with Regex and replace its value

Tags: java, xml, regex

I understand that I should not use Regex to update xml. But as per the requirement I have to find element based on regex and replace its value. 
I am recording all the HTTP requests in dispatcher servlet and saving it intoa file. While replaying it I may need to upadte one of the xml. 
I don't want to convert that particular xml into `Document`, parse and update it then convert it back to String. That's why I want to edit xml in String format.
Element name and its new value will be my input.
so

```
public void findAndReplace(String xml, String elementName, String newValue)
{
 String regex = '/<'+elementName+'></'+elementName+'>';
 String updatedElement = '/<'+elementName+'>'+newValue+'</'+elementName+'>'

 String updatedXML = xml.replaceFirst(regex, updatedElement);
}
```

Comment: Use an XML parser.  *"But as per the requirement"*  What complete idiot made that requirement?  They should be drawn and quartered.

Comment: if you want to FIND something in an XML use XPath

Comment: @AndrewThompson I am actually recording all the HTTP request xmls in a file and may have to update 1 or two of them. We don't want to convert each xml into a Document so that they could be editable.

Comment: @Eugene I don't have luxury to convert it into a Document, find element, update it and then convert it back into String and dispatch my request xml.

Comment: @HimanshuYadav  That explanation made absolutely no sense to me.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Updated my question. Hope that helps.

Comment: *"I don't want.."*  Not to put too fine a point on it, but what you want is not as important as what will work.

Comment: What is the purpose of the `/` before the `<`? Also, what is your actual question?

Comment: That is just String manipulation not regular expression. I need regular expression to find given xml tag with any value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't necessarily have to create a `Document` in order to change an XML document. You can quite easily set up streaming XML parser to do this in an efficient manner. Have a look at the `javax.xml.stream` package.